# Conditionally upsert records in knex

Tags: knex.js

I'm doing an upsert into postgres using knex, and in case of conflict (and subsequent update) I only want to update the conflicting row if the existing value in a column (timestamp) is less than the incoming value.

```js
await dbClient(table)
  .insert(records)
  .onConflict("digits")
  .merge();
```

I want the merge to occur if the act_ts field (timestamp) in the indiviual record (from records array) is larger than what the existing column value.

I was trying the following code

```js
await dbClient(table)
  .insert(records)
  .onConflict("digits")
  .merge().where('act_ts','<',???);
```

How do I reference the value in the incoming object to do a comparison against it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching the PostgreSQL documentation, I found that there is a reserved wored 'EXCLUDED' that references the data row that conflicted so I did the following:

```
const response = await dbClient(table)
  .insert(records)
  .onConflict("digits")
  .merge().whereRaw(`${table}.act_ts < EXCLUDED.act_ts`);
```

Where `${table}.act_ts` references the data already in the table and `EXCLUDED.act_ts` the incoming value.

Works as expected.